# Returning multliple value of a column concatenated

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables like this.

Person

```
ID | FirstName | LastName | 
----------------------------
1  | Tim       | yank
2  | Nick      | Thomas
3  | Leo       | Peter
4  | Frank     | Thomas
5  | George    | Hick
6  | Joe       | Moses
```

**Hobbies_person**

```
HobbyID | personID |
----------------------------
1       | 1 
3       | 1
4       | 1
2       | 2
2       | 4
3       | 3
4       | 2
4       | 5
2       | 5
1       | 6
```

Hobbies :

```
ID   | Name
------------
1    | Soccer
2    | Fishing
3    | Hiking
4    | Painting
```

I want to do a query like  when i give a person id it should give me first name  last name & hobby.
If a person has more than 1 hobby (like personid 1) result should be like
Tim,  Yank,  (1,  3,  4)--> all hobbies as a string seperated by a ,

Not able to do the hobbies concatenation.

Comment: Check GROUP_CONCAT MySQL command,
Btw - is it SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: you should tag your dbms

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT  works like a charm